# Using Jquery Flip with multiple items

Tags: jquery, flip

I am trying to use jQuery Flip v1.0.12 based off the "Grid Style" documentation here:

[Under Grid style example](http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/)

The problem is, when I use the manual trigger and add buttons to flip the card from front to back, only the button in the first card works, but it flips all of the items simultaneously.

Is there a way to bind the click for each item so that I can correct the problem that I am experiencing?

```
 $(".card-grid").flip({
     trigger: 'manual'
 });

 $("#flip-btn").click(function(){
     $(".card-grid").flip(true);
 });

 $("#unflip-btn").click(function(){
     $(".card-grid").flip(false);
 });
```

View the JS fiddle example for my current code

Here is my example and issue: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yf8n6upe/1/)

Comment: ids must be *unique*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass all IDs to class and then use closest inside your script in order to only flip the given element:

```
$(".card-grid").flip({
    trigger: 'manual'
});
$(".flip-btn").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".card-grid").flip(true);
});
$(".unflip-btn").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".card-grid").flip(false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yf8n6upe/2/

Comment: brilliant! Thank you, I would not have figured that out.